# Reemplazar numero de array por una x si encuentra coincidencia con un random en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, poo, algoritmos

Tengo un array con 5 numeros, genero un numero random y si esta dentro del array debo reemplazarlo por una x, consigo hacer esto, pero a la siguiente vez se me borro la x antes conseguida.O sea no mantiene el resultado obtenido antes. Es un bingo

```js
var randomNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1)
console.log("Soy random " +randomNum)

var myCard=[2,12,15,8,7]

//console.log(myCard)

for(var x=0;x<myCard.length;x++){

  if(randomNum===myCard[x]){
    myCard[x]='X'
  }
  console.log(myCard[x])
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que a la siguiente vez se te borro la x antes conseguida? Yo he ejecutado tu ejemplo y parece funcionar perfectamente.

Comment: Hola, a que deberia ser el mecanismo de un bingo y mantenerme los aciertos existentes para poder llegar a hacer linea o bingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo que quieres es que se repita hasta que alguien consiga hacer bingo, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar un bucle `while` conteniendo todo el código que tienes actualmente para que se ejecute no una sola vez si no n veces, en este caso, hasta que un contador indique que se han completado todos los números del array. Para ello, cada vez que se acierta un número sumo uno al contador.

```js
var myCard=[2,12,15,8,7]
var contador=0

while (contador < myCard.length){
  var randomNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1)
  console.log("Soy random " +randomNum)

  for(var x=0;x<myCard.length;x++){

    if(randomNum===myCard[x]){
      myCard[x]='X'
      contador++
    }
    console.log(myCard[x])
  }
}

console.log("BINGOOOO!!!!");
```

Comment: Parece buena idea y creo que por ahi va el tema, solo que probando desde aqui, si lo miras no mantiene las x anteriores. De todas formas seguiré probando. Muchas gracias !!!

Comment: @gastónartazayañez ¿A que te refieres con que no mantiene las x anteriores? Si te fijas, al ejecutarlo, te aparece el array con todas las X que hay hasta el momento. En caso de que el número no esté en el array, te mantiene las X, en caso contrario, añade la X en el número en cuestión.

Comment: sisi, tienes razón, ahora lo probé bien y es asi, es un buen punto. Iré implementando mas cosas para que se parezca más a un bingo real.      Gracias compi!!!

Comment: @gastónartazayañez No hay de que!! Si te ha servido la respuesta por favor considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada para que otros usuarios sepan que te ha servido para resolver el problema. Y si tienes más dudas... no dudes en volver a preguntar!! :P